# STOPPED WORKING: Opening Excel file on sharepoint as data source using ADODB connection

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, adodb

I have been using the following vba macro to open a file from sharepoint. It worked great for a long time, and then all of a sudden I am getting this error

```
run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Failure Creating File
```

When I try to debug, the strpath is highlighted.

```
Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    With oConn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .Properties("Extended Properties").Value = "Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES" 'Excel 12.0
        .Open strPath
```

I am using a public function to change the format of the file path (remove "HTTPS:", change "/" with "\" and spaces are already represented by "%20"):

```
sLink = Replace(sLink, "https:", "")
fnCleanupLink = Replace(sLink, "/", "\")
```

Like I said, this has worked previously and for a long while. I have tried trouble shooting and my code still works with a file saved on my hard-drive. When I try to manually open the link from excel I get the hyperlink warning, and then once I click 'Ok' it opens the file. Could this be causing the error?

Comment: Where do you assign `strpath`? What is the value of `strpath` before the `.Open strPath`? Write `MsgBox strpath` on the line before and see.

Comment: strpath is defined at the beginning of the macro, Dim strPath As String
and strPath = fnCleanupLink(wsAdmin.Range(sRange)) (sRange is also defined at beginning of macro). The strpath is exactly what I would expect it to be, no HTTPS:, \\ instead of / and %20 for spaces

Comment: Have you checked that the path is still valid? I suspect your path has changed

Comment: Yes, the path is still valid - when I try to open it with explorer it works. I have also tried updating it just in case and still get the same error